# Pipe subscriptions not called when observer used in a forkJoin

Tags: angular, rxjs

Here a code example :

```typescript
const obs1 = ajax.getJSON("https://api.github.com/users/google");
obs1.pipe(
  map(result => {
    console.log("map");
    console.log(result);
    return result;
  })
);

/*
  when all observables complete, provide the last
  emitted value from each as dictionary
*/
forkJoin([obs1])
  // { google: object, microsoft: object, users: array }
  .subscribe(result => {
    console.log("forkJoin");
    console.log(result);
  });
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-fuhehc?file=index.ts&devtoolsheight=100

Why pipe subscriptions are not called by the forkJoin ?

Comment: [What are operators?](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/operators) A Pipeable Operator is a function that takes an Observable as its input and returns another Observable. It is a pure operation: the previous Observable stays unmodified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You subscribed to your obs1 observable, not the second one you declared:

```js
const obs1 = ajax.getJSON("https://api.github.com/users/google");
const obs2 = obs1.pipe(
  map(result => {
    console.log("map");
    console.log(result);
    return result;
  })
);

/*
  when all observables complete, provide the last
  emitted value from each as dictionary
*/
forkJoin([obs2])
  // { google: object, microsoft: object, users: array }
  .subscribe(result => {
    console.log("forkJoin");
    console.log(result);
  });
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-qiwftr?devtoolsheight=33&file=index.ts